# How to find the file associated with a memory mapped address in C

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-mapped-files

Is there an existing example of how, in C, to take a memory address and get which, if any, file is mapped to that address?

Specifically, I am modifying how msync works and I want to know what file is associated with the address being synced.

I can see how in the [proc man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) such a thing could be found by looking at the contents of the /proc/self/map_files directory, but I am hoping there is an already existing helper function for doing this.

Comment: There is no general answer. E.G., create a file, mmap it, then delete the file. You still have the open reference, but there is no directory entry pointing to the file. You may be able to find the inode, but I don't know how offhand.

Comment: It is possible, see the linked man page.  There is some code in lsof source package for doing this, but it is buried.  I was hoping for something standalone.